# Angular momentum in mono-propeller flying vehicle

Tags: angular-momentum

I am trying to build a mono-propeller drone, and I'm concerned with the rotation of the vehicle due to the rotation of the propeller. Conservation of angular momentum would cause this, but would the reaction caused by pushing the air cause it to spin even more? The reason I’m asking this is because I want to counter this rotation with an inverse spinning load, but I don’t know if I have to add more weight than that of the spinning propeller mass to account for this secondary effect. Also, if someone has a better idea on how to solve this issue I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not conservation of angular momentum, it is Newton's third law of motion that should concern you. For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction. The motor shaft spins the prop against air resistance, the motor housing spins the craft with an equal force in the opposite direction. This is why helicopters have the tail rotor, to push against the reaction of the main rotor. Before quadcopters were popular they made RC copters with two rotors on top that spun in opposite directions to counter each other. An opposite spinning load would not help (unless it had air resistance equal to the propeller).